# Jenkins and AWS Elasctic Beanstalk deployment

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What i'm looking for is this kind of stack:

CI: Jenkins

Plugins: [M2 Release](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin), [AWSEB Deployment Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWSEB+Deployment+Plugin)

1. pom.xml version is 1.0-SNAPSHOT.
2. When i push to github, Jenkins creates a project-1.0-SNAPSHOT package and deploys it automatically on test server with AWSEB Deployment Plugin.
3. Once all devs are good on test server, I manually deploy on production the current snapshot with M2 Release and AWSEB Deployment Plugin.
4. pom.xml version on github is now set to 1.1-SNAPSHOT.

Does anyone has a similar stack, or has some usefull resources to do the entire chain ?

Answer (score 0):

The AWSEB Deployment Plugin is just a focused version of [beanstalker](http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br).

Actually, you can use something combining the maven-release-plugin (although I'd suggest using only [versions](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) instead) with beanstalker, like this:

http://www.nagaseyasuhito.net/2012/03/26/211/

Comment: Dude i don't speak japanese :p